# Consolidating aspnetcore items in Startup, without duplicating service registrations or pipelines

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to consolidate all of the junk that I'm generating in a project that's turning my Startup class into a dumping ground. However, it's not clear that the clean-up and consolidation can coexist with other libraries that attempt to do the same thing. For example, other libraries may need to call these in `ConfigureServices()`:

```cs
services.Configure<AuthorizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AddSomePolicies();
});
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(MyAttribute));
});
services.AddSignalR().AddMyCustomBackplane();
```

I wouldn't likely have the only library needing to add some auth policies, or filters or activate SignalR. I can't prove to myself that wrapping all of these in a `services.MyUltimateExtension()` doesn't lead to a mess.

Similarly, I can't easily encapsulate these in the `Configure()` method to my own library method:

```cs
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<MyHub>("/MyHub");
});
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.AddMyRoutes(app);
}
```

To me this sets up multiple MVC pipelines and maybe duplicates SignalR infrastructure.

What do I do? I'm concerned about readability for other developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That got me wondering, so I had a look at the way the `UseMvc` and `AddMvc` work, and I can say that it's safe to call them multiple times (**with caveats**).

### `UseMvc`

`UseMvc` does two things: register the MVC services, and set up the wanted MVC options.

When registering the services, it calls the [`IServiceCollection.TryAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.extensions.servicecollectiondescriptorextensions.tryadd?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method, which doesn't register a service that's already registered. That means all MVC services are registered only once.

For the options, it calls the [`IServiceCollection.Configure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method. The final options is built by calling each configuring action successively. For example:

Calling:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.EnableEndpointRouting = true;
});

services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    options.MaxValidationDepth = 3;
});
```

is equivalent to:

```cs
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.EnableEndpointRouting = true;

    // the last options win
    options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    options.MaxValidationDepth = 3;
});
```

As you can see, the calling order is important, because it can override some previously set options. **It's safe if there's no overlap.**

### `AddMvc`

`AddMvc` does one thing: add a new instance of the [MVC routing middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Http/Routing/src/RouterMiddleware.cs) each time that method is called.

Conceptually, that means that calling:

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "blog",
        template: "Blog/{**article}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "ReadArticle" });
});
```

is equivalent to calling:

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "blog",
        template: "Blog/{**article}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "ReadArticle" });
});
```

Note that if there's an overlap between the routing, the MVC framework will reject the query with an `AmbiguousMatchException`.

Trying to access `/Blog/this-is/a/test` will fail:

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "blog",
        template: "Blog/{**article}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "ReadArticleOne" });
});

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "blog",
        template: "Blog/{**article}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "ReadArticleTwo" });
});
```

---

So, what should you do? What I did when my `Startup.cs` was getting crowded was to set up a number of extension methods grouped by intent and split up in multiple classes, without worrying about having multiple calls to `UseMvc` or `AddMvc`. The only thing you have to keep in mind is the calling order.

Comment: That's fantastic, and takes care of some of the big chunks. Maybe I need to dig in to the source for auth options and SignalR.